# How to save memory when using multiprocessing.map?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a function that basically takes a pair of integers `(x,y)` and produce a vector with like 3000 elements. So, I used:

```
pool_obj=multiprocessing.Pool()
result=np.array(pool_obj.map(f, RANGE))
```

where `RANGE` is the Cartesian product of the two sets of values x,y may take respectively.

My problem is that all I need is `np.sum(result,axis=0)` which is 3000 long. I want to sum over all x and y. There are 1000x1000 pairs of `(x,y)` in total. Using this approach will create a super huge array that is 1000000x3000 big and exceeds the memory limit.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: if `RANGE` is a generator rather than an array, `pool.map` should only generate inputs on the fly as needed. then as long as the output of `f` is small, there shouldn't be excessive memory usage.

Comment: The docs for ``Pool.map`` note that "Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables. *Consider using ``imap()`` or ``imap_unordered()`` with explicit chunksize option for better efficiency.*". Did you try these instead?

Comment: There is an additional requirement that the iterator must have a `__len__` method, or the pool **will** compute all the inputs ahead of time. This is because it tries to use `len` when determining chunk size, output size, and when checking if the input is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot! imap_unordered is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using a generator for `x, y` pairs to reduce input size, while using `imap` to reduce output size (reduce data as it comes in back to the main process)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

class yield_xy:
    """
    Generator for x, y pairs prevents all pairs of x and y from being generated
    at the start of the map call. In this example it would only be a million
    floats, so on the order of 4-8 Mb of data, but if x, and y are bigger
    (or maybe you have a z) this could dramatically reduce input data size
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        
    def __len__(self): #map, imap, map_async, starmap etc.. need the input size ahead of time
        return len(self._x) * len(self._y)
    
    def __iter__(self): #simple generator needs storage x + y rather than x * y
        for x in self._x:
            for y in self._y:
                yield x, y

def task(args):
    x, y = args
    return (np.zeros(3000) + x) * y


def main():
    x = np.arange(0,1000)
    y = np.sin(x)
    
    out = np.zeros(3000)
    
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(task, yield_xy(x, y)):
            out += result #accumulate results
    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = main()
```